# Oracle 11g - Merging single column duplicates to create a vertical summary

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, duplicates, distinct

Does anybody know how to remove and merge duplicates based on a single column of a multi-column table to create a 'vertical summary'.

I.E) Trying to build Table B from Table A

```
Table A:
Person Language
Bob    English
Sarah  French
John   Chinese
Bob    French
Sarah  English
Sarah  Chinese

Table B (RESULT): 
Person English French Chinese 
Bob       Y       Y     (null)
Sarah     Y       Y       Y
John      (null)  (null)  Y
```

How I was thinking originally of doing it was:
Creating Table A from the data and then doing the following:

```
Create table summary as 
Select person, (case when language = 'English' then 'Y') as English, (case when        language = 'French' then 'Y') as French, (case when language = 'Chinese' then 'Y') as  Chinese
From Table A;
```

Finally doing a select distinct of the summary table. 
The logic is however wrong, especially because distinct does so across all columns, but I only want distinct people names.

The other option I was thinking of in my head was Creating a table populated with only the distinct names of people and empty columns English, French and Chinese. Then using an update statement to populate them via matching to Table A.

Does anybody know a better way / how I could implement this. I'm still in the earlier stages of learning Oracle (especially regarding looping) and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has a [Decode function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php).

But what you're looking for is a [pivot](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506)

```
WITH pivot_data AS (
    SELECT Person, Language
    FROM   A
)
SELECT *
FROM   pivot_data
PIVOT (
    Count(*)        --<-- pivot_clause
    FOR Language         --<-- pivot_for_clause
    IN  ('English', 'French', 'Chinese')   --<-- pivot_in_clause
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Create table summary 
as  
Select 
    person, 
    min(case when language = 'English' then 'Y' end) as English, 
    min(case when language = 'French' then 'Y' end) as French, 
    min(case when language = 'Chinese' then 'Y' end) as  Chinese 
From 
    Table A
group by 
    person
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as Sjuul, using [pivot](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#sthref6775), but this gives you the `Y`/`null` values you wanted:

```
select * from (
    select person, language, 'Y' as flag from tablea
)
pivot (max(flag) for language
    in ('English' as english, 'French' as french, 'Chinese' as chinese));
```

So to create a new table based on that:

```
create table tableb as
select * from (
    select person, language, 'Y' as flag from tablea
)
pivot (max(flag) for language
    in ('English' as english, 'French' as french, 'Chinese' as chinese));

Table created.

select * from tableb order by person;

PERSON          E F C
--------------- - - -
Bob             Y Y
John                Y
Sarah           Y Y Y
```

If the data in `tablea` is going to change, you might be better off making `tableb` a view so it doesn't go out of step.